# How To Execute /bin Functions From The Python Terminal?

Tags: bash, python

I'm actually running a python *interpreter* through a Linux bash terminal, and I'd like to be able to execute some of the bash commands in /bin through the python interpreter. How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Comment: This worked! But how would I store the output as a string? I'd like to use the <string>.find() function, but assigning that call() line to a variable didn't work.

Comment: Have a look to the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html ... you will find examples there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run some of the basic OS commands, check out Python's OS module https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html and the subprocess module https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html

The OS module provides the simplest way to interact with the OS in python.

`>>> import os`

`>>> os.listdir('/bin')`

Would list the file contents in the /bin directory, as an example.

Can you be more specific on which bash commands you want to run?

Comment: Sure, I want access to my strace, csf, netstat, etc, commands without having to to import entire libraries to replace them.

Comment: In that case, I don't think there are any built in methods/commands that actually run OS commands. I believe you will have no choice but importing at least the os or subprocess module. Someone smarter than myself may give you other information, but based on my experience, you will have to import at least one module to gain access to the OS.